# perl program to replace a string in a file multiple times

Tags: perl, replace

I would like to replace "int" with "int int int" in a file practice.py. The below code is not working.

```
perl -p -i -e "s/int/int{3}/g" practice.py;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -p -i -e "s/int/int int int/g" practice.py;
```

The `{3}` can only be used to match in a regex not in a substitution.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i -pe 's/(int)\K/ $1 $1/g' practice.py
```

(`-pe ".."` if using windows)

Comment: Lack of explanation, probably.